# Show Dialog in Android produces crash

Tags: java, android, dialog

I hava a problem with a ProgressDialog in my App. 
I'm doing some tasks in background and notify actions to my Activity using a Handler.
Sometimes, not always, when I try to show my Dialog app crashes and appears this exception:

```
android.view.windowleaked
```

The way of dialog is launched:

```
try {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(VoiceAcquisitionActivity.this);
    pd.setMessage("blablabla");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've read and this exception is normal in `.dismiss()` operation but in `.show()`??

How can I avoid this problem?

Thanks

Comment: is your activity running ?

Comment: Yes, because this code is called in Activity

Comment: sorry, can you remove my package name? thanks

Comment: Can please add the complete logcat report

Comment: share full code are u calling this in background or in ui thread?

Answer (score 1):

for safety you could wrap your dialog logic in a block of code like:

```
   if(!isFinishing()){

       pd = newProgressDialog(VoiceAcquisitionActivity.this);                                 
       pd.setMessage("Loading message");
       pd.setCancelable(false);
       pd.show();
   }
```

Comment: I don't think this solution fix, because Activity isn't finished when receives this message

Comment: @user3086708 this is a safety check since, if your Activity isFinishing it will not attempt to show a dialog without having the activity for context. It seems the issue is your activity is crashing and your attempting to show a dialog during this crash. please post your full stack trace